# UWP C# - How to display "non-static" elements in Visual Studio Designer?

Tags: c#, uwp, designer, visual-studio-community

My problem is that my Visual Studio (Visual Studio Community 2017, UWP C# Project) doesn't want to show me my AppBar or ListView template elements in the Designer. When I run the app (Windows 10), both are there, but there must be a way to display the elements that are built into the ListView template in the Designer, or at least my AppBar should be displayed, right?

Example code:

```
<Page
x:Class="Rechnungswesen.Views.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Rechnungswesen.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:Rechnungswesen.Data"
mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Increment" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Increment"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Remove" Label="Decrement" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Decrement"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0 0 1 2" SelectionMode="None" Padding="0 10" ItemsSource="{x:Bind balanceAssets}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ItemData">
                    <Grid Margin="0 0 2 0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding number, Mode=TwoWay}" GotFocus="textBoxGotFocus" LostFocus="itemNumberLostFocus"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15 0 0 0"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding sum, Mode=TwoWay}" GotFocus="textBoxGotFocus" LostFocus="sumLostFocus" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Have you tried to decrease target version to 15063 ?

Comment: Well, that workes actually. Thank you! Could you tell me, why it has to be that version? I mean, I don't care about which version I'm using, but I guess it would be good to know about, at least.

Comment: I have report this issue to Visual Studio Developer Community. Please follow the [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/153030/visual-studio-desgintime-does-not-work-within-wind.html) updates。